# Catch http errors when using jQuery to modify styles globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As I can not comment because I am a new user, I am posting this question as separate one. This question is related to [Can I catch http errors when using jQuery to modify styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593492/can-i-catch-http-errors-when-using-jquery-to-modify-styles)

Let us say I have a **HTML5 REST** based application created using **Javascript**, **JQuery** and **AngularJS** frameworks.

In the below snippet I have a `background-image` URL, if the image is not found I will get a 404 error. The snippet is **dynamically** generated, based on some **JSON data** coming from the external API. In some cases I might be having broken URLs for images.

What I am looking for is to handle all such errors globally and avoid calling one error type on each element that triggered the error.

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://somedomain.com/uploads/images/qq);"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008150/detecting-broken-css-background-images-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: Hello @juvian. The solution I am looking for is not the same as the one you suggested. I am looking for a hook or handler where I can handle all such kind of errors so that I can log them to some central server.

Comment: @Vijay (apache) servers log 404 by default

Comment: @Vijay you can just make an ajax to your sever to log the error inside the error callback

Comment: @MattBurland, I tried the below approaches, but no luck.  It doesn't fire the methods at all. :)  `window.onerror = function () {
            console.log("Something gone wrong");
        }` and `window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
            console.log("Something gone wrong");
            console.log(e.error.message, "from", e.error.stack);
        });`

Comment: @Vijay: What do you mean by "no luck"? Does it give you error messages? Does it not get fired at all? Does it do something else? It would probably help to add that attempt to your question.

Comment: @MattBurland, It doesn't fire the methods at all. :)

Comment: With background images, there is no event; you have check yourself.

Comment: @juvian. Do you recommend to change the above to image tag and give the url as the source instead? Then would the error events fire?

Comment: @Vijay not sure it will raise the window.onerror, but with img you can use <img src="http://somedomain.com/uploads/images/qq" onError = "console.log('error')"></img>

Comment: @juvian. Yes you are right, we can raise the exception on individual element like you shown, but what I am looking for is kind of global handler that can catch any exception that is thrown for the images.

Comment: @Vijay just add the onError to all images, and make it run your global handler